# How to connect to svn repository

Tags: svn

I followed this tutorial to create a svn repository on my vps: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/12342/how-to-install-and-use-svn-on-centos-6

Now I want to checkout the repository to my computer. I installed TortoiseSVN but I'm not sure what URL to enter. I tried svn://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/my-test-repos/ which didn't work:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
 'svn://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/my-test-repos/'
Can't connect to host 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx'
```

Is this the correct URL?

Or do I need to make the repository accessible somehow?

Comment: That link shows nothing about setting up a *server* on a godaddy host, just how to use `svn` *on* that host when logged in to a shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at your tutorial.

In fact, the tutorial doesn't explain how to build a remote repository (e.g on another server). It let you only create a local repository to keep your version tracked.

Since you are trying to access a repository on your computer and according to the tutorial the url should be `file://$HOME/.svnrepos/my-test-repos/trunk`.

When you are using `svn://` or `http://` protocols to access a svn repository, it means it's on anoter `computer/server`. Here, your svn repos is local, so it should be : `file://pathtoyourlocalrepository/`